# Problems with Big O Notation

Tags: python, dictionary, big-o, binary-search-tree, doubly-linked-list

I created two dictionaries, one using doubly linked lists and another using binary search trees, both with some basic functions. I want to estimate the Big O notation for both dictionaries and compare them alongside the native Python dictionary, but I'm facing some issues.

I know that the native dictionary is supposed to be O(1), the list dictionary O(n), and the tree dictionary O(log(n)), but that's not what I'm finding when I generate dictionaries of all three types randomly. What could be the issue? When I try to plot it, it looks like it's kinda alright, but analyzing the times in a list, they are randomly increasing.

The code:

```
class dict_linear:
 class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, value, prev=None, next=None):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = next

 def __init__(self):
    self.firstNode = None

 def search(self, key):
    curr = self.firstNode
    while curr is not None:
        if curr.key == key:
            return curr
        curr = curr.next
    return None

 def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    curr = self.search(key)
    if curr is not None:
        curr.value = value
    else:
        new_node = self.Node(key, value)
        if self.firstNode is None:
            self.firstNode = new_node
        else:
            new_node.next = self.firstNode
            self.firstNode.prev = new_node
            self.firstNode = new_node

 def __getitem__(self, key):
    curr = self.search(key)
    if curr is None:
        raise KeyError(f"There was an error with the key '{key}'")
    return curr.value

class dict_binary:
 class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

 def __init__(self):
    self.root = None

 def search(self, curr, key):
    if curr is None or curr.key == key:
        return curr
    elif key < curr.key:
        return self.search(curr.left, key)
    else:
        return self.search(curr.right, key)   

 def insert(self, curr, key, value):
    if key == curr.key:
        curr.value = value
    elif key < curr.key:
        if curr.left is None:
            curr.left = self.Node(key, value)
        else:
            self.insert(curr.left, key, value)
    elif key > curr.key:
        if curr.right is None:
            curr.right = self.Node(key, value)
        else:
            self.insert(curr.right, key, value)

 def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if self.root is None:
        self.root = self.Node(key, value)
    else:
        self.insert(self.root, key, value)

 def __getitem__(self, key):
    curr = self.search(self.root, key)
    if curr is None:
        raise KeyError(f"There was an error with the key '{key}'")
    return curr.value
```

Comment: What do you mean with "but that's not what I'm finding when I generate dictionaries of all three types randomly"? Big O tells you worst case runtime complexity as `n` increases, so the only way to empirically test that is to run the same test with more and more input until things take so long that your computer can't finish the task in a reasonable amount of time, then plotting the time required against the input size for each test. Which won't give you a true Big O, but should at least give the rough shape of the runtime complexity function for you to guestimate an upper bound for.

Comment: *I know the native dictionary is supposed to be O(1)* -- WHAT is O(1)?  Do you mean looking up an item?  Because adding and deleting might be quite different.

Comment: I understand what you guys mean, I thought it had to be stricly that Big O, but you have an expected one and worst scenario one, and it depends on what operation you doing as well, think I got it.

Comment: @lifezbeautiful I didn't edit their post. Head on over to the [edit history](/posts/76641008/revisions) to see all users that did.